# Scala type bounds and Java generic interop

Tags: scala

I'm trying to wrap the rxjava's `timeout` [method](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/f5314b1b53e6ecb7cf78acd2106fc2ed69a6b102/rxjava-core/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L6633) as to make it available [for scala](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/master/language-adaptors/rxjava-scala/src/main/scala/rx/lang/scala/Observable.scala).

Similar to [many other methods](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/master/language-adaptors/rxjava-scala/src/main/scala/rx/lang/scala/Observable.scala#L1365) I tried this:

```
def timeout[U >: T](timeout: Duration, other: Observable[U]): Observable[U] = {
  val otherJava: rx.Observable[_ <: U] = other.asJavaObservable
  val thisJava:  rx.Observable[_ <: U] = this.asJavaObservable
  toScalaObservable[U](thisJava.timeout(timeout.length, timeout.unit, otherJava))
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Observable.scala:1631: error: overloaded method value timeout with alternatives:
($1: Long,x$2: java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,x$3: rx.Scheduler)rx.Observable[_$85] <and>
($1: Long,x$2: java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,x$3: rx.Observable[_ <: _$85])rx.Observable[_$85]
cannot be applied to (Long, scala.concurrent.duration.TimeUnit, rx.Observable[_$84])
  toScalaObservable[U](thisJava.timeout(timeout.length, timeout.unit, otherJava))
```

The original java method:

```
public Observable<T> timeout(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit, Observable<? extends T> other) {
   return create(OperationTimeout.timeout(this, timeout, timeUnit, other));
}
```

I'm not very familiar with neither Java nor Scala (and all the type bounds) but as far as I understand: Both `otherJava` as well as `thisJava` is of type `rx.Observable[U]`, so why don't they line up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hum, your are stepping right on the variance problems of Java generics used in Scala. Let's go step by step.

---

Let's look at your implementation:

```
// does not compile (with your original error)
def timeout[U >: T](timeout: Duration, other: Observable[U]): Observable[U] = {
  val otherJava: rx.Observable[_ <: U] = other.asJavaObservable
  val thisJava:  rx.Observable[_ <: U] = this.asJavaObservable
  toScalaObservable[U](thisJava.timeout(timeout.length, timeout.unit, otherJava))
}
```

To understand why this won't work, let's call `A` the unnamed type in the declaration of `thisJava` (the `A <: U` such that `thisJava` is a `rx.Observable[A]`). The `timeout` method of `thisJava: rx.Observable[A]` expects a parameter of type `rx.Observable[_ <: A]`, and you give it one of type `rx.Observable[_ <: U]`: the compiler has no way to know how those two types are related. They might not be related at all!

On the other hand, if `A` were `U`, then `thisJava` would be a `rx.Observable[U]`, and its `timeout` method would expect a `rx.Observable[_ <: U]`, which just happen to be the type of `otherJava`. Let's try:

```
// still does not compile, sadly
def timeout[U >: T](timeout: Duration, other: Observable[U]): Observable[U] = {
  val otherJava: rx.Observable[_ <: U] = other.asJavaObservable
  val thisJava:  rx.Observable[U] = this.asJavaObservable // variance error
  toScalaObservable[U](thisJava.timeout(timeout.length, timeout.unit, otherJava))
}
```

In a perfect world, the above would work. *However*, the java `rx.Observable` isn't defined as covariant since there is no definition-site variance annotations in java. So Scala believes it is invariant.

Hence as far as Scala is concerned, a `rx.Observable[_ <: U]` is **not** a `rx.Observable[U]`, and  sadly `this.asJavaObservable` returns a `rx.Observable[_ <: U]`.

---

But we know [*] that `rx.Observable<T>` should be covariant, so we can just blindly cast away:

```
// this compiles and *should* work
def timeout[U >: T](timeout: Duration, other: Observable[U]): Observable[U] = {
  val otherJava: rx.Observable[_ <: U] = other.asJavaObservable
  val thisJava = this.asJavaObservable.asInstanceOf[rx.Observable[U]]
  toScalaObservable[U](thisJava.timeout(timeout.length, timeout.unit, otherJava))
}
```

The moral of this story is that mixing Scala's variance and Java's variance will always cost you a few cast here and there, that must be carefully thought about.

Also, making `asJavaObservable` return a `rx.Observable[T]` instead of `_ <: T` would make all this easier, but maybe there are good reasons why it isn't the case...

[*] more like "but I suspect"

Comment: But then I have lost the flexibility of passing a supertype Observable as `other`. I think for more flexibility, the library should allow a different type `U`. Also note that `<? extends T>` is indeed translated to `[_ <: T]` as [noted in the scala history](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/changelog.html#java_generics)

Comment: @Aralo oh, you are completely right. Actually, it wouldn't even compile without some `U` type parameter because a covariant type cannot appear (in `other`) in a contravariant position. I removed my first point and updated the code.

Comment: Great explanation. I do follow your argument and it does work (see [my pull request](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/pull/720)).

However, it's still confusing since I thought that they are the same type. Let's test it with `List` which is also covariant: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6692064/ That's why I thought that they're both the /exact same/ type. Still confusing.

Answer (score 3):

[this should go into the comments of @gourlaysama's answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment]

@Aralo The statement "`MyType[_ <: T]` is the same as `MyType[T]`" only holds if *the compiler knows* that `MyType` is covariant. This is the case with `List`, because it's defined as `List[+A]`, but it's not the case with `rx.Observable`, because it's a Java type, so its type parameters cannot have variance annotations, so the compiler cannot know that it's intended to be covariant.

@gourlaysama making `asJavaObservable` return a `rx.Observable[T]` instead of `_ <: T` is not the solution, because the type `rx.lang.scala.Observable[T]` means "an Observable of `T` or of something which is a subtype of `T`", and this description corresponds exactly to the type `rx.Observable[_ <: T]` (which is the same as `rx.Observable<? extends T>`).

The reason why we have to cast in Scala is that the signature of `timeout` in Java is "wrong": Strictly speaking, it makes the Java Observable invariant, because `T` appears in a contravariant position. The "correct" way would be to use another type parameter `U`, whose lower bound is `T`, as in Scala, but Java doesn't support lower bounds, so the best solution is to keep the "wrong" solution. This problem occurs also with `reduce` (see [this comment](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/issues/336#issuecomment-24094254)), `onErrorReturn`, and a few other operators.

In general, all these operators which should have a lower bounded type parameter (but don't) can only be used on an `Observable<T>`, but not on an `Observable<? extends T>` (a quite serious inconvenience for Java users), and thus, they require a cast in the Scala adaptor.