# How to use EqualsWithDelta of junit

Tags: scala, unit-testing, junit, matcher

versions:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to use [EqualsWithDelta](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.9.5/org/mockito/internal/matchers/EqualsWithDelta.html) like below, which is not working, however in similar way [Equals](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.9.5/org/mockito/internal/matchers/Equals.html) works, is there something I am missing in my implementation:

```
import org.junit.Assert
import org.mockito.internal.matchers.{Equals, EqualsWithDelta}
val testVarLong = testFuncReturningLong()
val testVarStr = testFuncReturningString()
Assert.assertThat( System.currentTimeMillis(), new EqualsWithDelta(testVarLong, 1000L))      <-- This does not  work
Assert.assertThat( "myTest", new Equals(testVarStr))   <-- This works
```

Following is compile time error I get:

```
Error:(82, 52) type mismatch;
 found   : org.mockito.internal.matchers.EqualsWithDelta
 required: org.hamcrest.Matcher[_ >: Any]
Note: Number <: Any (and org.mockito.internal.matchers.EqualsWithDelta <: org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher[Number]), but Java-defined trait Matcher is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
    Assert.assertThat( System.currentTimeMillis(), new EqualsWithDelta(testVarLong, 1000L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new EqualsWithDelta(...)` is a `Matcher[Number]`. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is a `Long`. `Assert.assertThat` signature is `assertThat(T actual, org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> matcher)`. So `EqualsWithDelta` must be a subtype of `Matcher<T>` and `Long` must be a subtype of `T`. The first implies `T` must be `Number`, but `Long` isn't a subtype of `Number`. So type inference reports such a `T` doesn't exist.

However, if you ask for `Number` explicitly in one of two ways:

```
assertThat[Number](System.currentTimeMillis(), new EqualsWithDelta(testVarLong, 1000L))

assertThat(System.currentTimeMillis(): Number, new EqualsWithDelta(testVarLong, 1000L))
```

this will trigger the [implicit conversion](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Predef$.html#long2Long(x:Long):Long) from `Long` to `java.lang.Long` as a subtype of `Number`.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Try casting</strike>

```
assertThat( System.currentTimeMillis(), new EqualsWithDelta(testVarLong, 1000L).asInstanceOf[Matcher[_ >: Long]])
```

or simply

```
assertThat[Long]( System.currentTimeMillis(), new EqualsWithDelta(testVarLong, 1000L).asInstanceOf[Matcher[Long]])
```

Anyway, at runtime `new EqualsWithDelta...` is just a `Matcher[_]` due to type erasure, so this casting is safe. **You should follow @AlexeyRomanov's advice.**

[Scala type bounds and Java generic interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912151/scala-type-bounds-and-java-generic-interop)

Comment: No casts should be needed if you use `assertThat[Number]` or `assertThat( System.currentTimeMillis(): Number, ...`.

Comment: Fair enough, added the answer.